# iSCSI Storage with Broadcom BCM5709 Offload in XenServer 6.2

Tags: iscsi, xenserver, broadcom

I'm in a process of migration from ESXi to XenServer. But we can't add our iSCSI Storage via Hardware HBA in XenServer 6.2.

I've tried to manually load bnx2i and cnic modules via modprobe but it has no effects and the LUN's does not appear in the New SR option.

It appears that I need an daemon named bnx2id; but I was not able to find it myself.

Looking forward for any help,

Comment: What does "we can't add our iSCSI Storage" mean? Elaborate on exactly how you're trying to add it, what error messages you get (if any) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you won't be able to add your iSCSI storage thought hardware with this board. Maybe the way to do it is by software iSCSI.

paranaue